# Webdriver/Firefox version issues

Tags: firefox, webdriver

As I read more on the use of webdriver/firefox, I am getting the impression that there serious issues regarding different versions - specifically that when a new version of FF comes out, a new version of WD is needed as well...

Am I reading this correctly?

If so, does the same problem exist with other browsers?

This is a worry for me because my clients may have different versions of FF, and because the app they get from me is compiled - which means I would need to send them an updated app every time FF is upgraded...

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver is updated on a consistent basis to stay current with the new browser versions that are coming out.  Firefox has a very fast release schedule.  For your application to support the very latest Firefox version, then you'll have to keep it updated with the latest WebDriver version that supports that version.

My advice is to tell your users which Firefox versions are supported by your application, and then setup a regular release cycle with them, in which you update WebDriver to work with the latest Firefox versions.  Then as new Firefox versions are released, you can update your application and send them the newest version.

Chrome is in a similar position, but for WebDriver, the Chromium team maintains the ChromeDriver, which doesn't always need update for each Chrome version.

Internet Explorer has a very slow release cycle, so you won't need to update the WebDriver assemblies as often for IE.

However, staying on the latest WebDriver version does have advantages, regardless of the browsers you need to support in your application, such as the latest bug fixes.

Comment: After reading more and learning that my suspicions were correct I considered using the HTMLunit version - which is in java, which I would have to learn. THEN I discovered that the java code can't be protected, even in a compiled state...so I am now looking at Beautifulsoup and am almost to the point I was with Webdriver. Of the two, I like WB better, but you got to work with what works...